# merging overlapping array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array like below:

```
$array1 = array(
               [0]=>array([0]=>a_a [1]=>aa)
               [1]=>array([0]=>b_b [1]=>bb) 
               [3]=>array([0]=>c_c [1]=>cc) 
               )


$array2 = array(
               [0]=>array([0]=>aa [1]=>AA)
               [1]=>array([0]=>bb [1]=>BB) 
               [3]=>array([0]=>cc [1]=>CC) 
               )
```

what i would like to merge or overlap to output like below:

```
$result = array(
               [0]=>array([0]=>a_a [1]=>AA)
               [1]=>array([0]=>b_b [1]=>BB) 
               [3]=>array([0]=>c_c [1]=>CC) 
               )
```

either output like below:

```
$result = array(
               [0]=>array([0]=>a_a [1]=>aa [2]=>AA)
               [1]=>array([0]=>b_b [1]=>bb [2]=>AA) 
               [3]=>array([0]=>c_c [1]=>cc [2]=>AA) 
               )
```

how i do this thing what is the best way any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don;t know which is the best way but you could do this with two loops. Example:

```
$result = array();
foreach($array1 as $val1) {
    foreach($array2 as $val2) {
        if($val1[1] == $val2[0]) {
            $result[] = array($val1[0], $val1[1], $val2[1]);
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

For the first result, its easily modifiable:

```
$result[] = array($val1[0], $val2[1]);
```

Comment: @codemania oh okay, i thought you said either, i just preferred the second one, anyway, check the revision

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function

1st output :

```
function my_array_merge(&$array1, &$array2) {
    $result = array();
    foreach($array1 as $key => &$value) {
        $result[$key] = array_unique(array_merge($value, $array2[$key]));
    }
    return $result;
}
$arr = my_array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

2st output :

```
function my_array_merge(&$array1, &$array2) {
    $result = array();
    foreach($array1 as $key => &$value) {
        $result[$key] = array_merge(array_diff($value, $array2[$key]), array_diff($array2[$key],$value));
    }
    return $result;
}
```